# Do relationships degrade over time?

Tags: stardew-valley

Will my relationships with the residents of Pelican Town degrade over time if I don't talk with them for a while? If so, how quickly does it degrade?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, relationships degrade over time if the friendship points were not maxed out. -2 points per day when ignored. +20 per day when talked to. Maxed-out friendship levels will not decay as of [patch 1.07.](http://steamcommunity.com/games/413150/announcements/detail/820027557812026939)

According to the [Stardew Valley wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Social):

> The social tab in your menu shows your current relationship with each
>   villager Each person shows a row of 10 hearts indicating your
>   relationship with them. If you're married, your spouse will have 12
>   hearts instead.
>
> The hearts will fill up or decrease over time as you talk to people
>   and gift them. You can give each person up to 2 gifts per week, as
>   indicated by the checkboxes to the right of their entry in the social
>   tab. Each heart represents 250 friendship points. Speaking to a
>   villager gives 20 points once per day, while ignoring them for a day
>   gives -2 points, so don't ignore your friends!
>
> Each villager has their own individual likes/dislikes. The more they
>   like a gift, the more invisible points you will get towards filling in
>   a heart; A loved gift is worth 80 points and a liked gift is worth 45.
>   Be careful, as gifting someone something they hate can also cause
>   hearts to go down.
>
> Successfully completing a quest that states it will make the villager
>   happy is worth 150 friendship points on immediate turn-in.
>
> Giving a villager a loved gift on their birthday nets you 640
>   friendship points (8x the value of a loved gift on a normal day) - it
>   pays to keep some diamonds around for those hard to please types. Even
>   a liked Birthday gift will net you 360 friendship points, so keeping
>   an eye on the calendar helps.

Comment: Do you have to finish the conversation (if they have multiple things to say?) in order to get the points / avoid the penalty?

Comment: No, just talking to them one time is fine.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that as of 1.07, maxed-out relationships no longer degrade over time (see the 11th bullet point [here](http://steamcommunity.com/games/413150/announcements/detail/820027557812026939))