# Do I need to talk to everyone everytime that there's a festival?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm in the 2nd year of my game, so I've seen all of the festivals already (and spoke with everyone at them during my 1st year). The NPCs don't seem to say anything different at festivals during the 2nd year.

**Is it safe to just not talk to every NPC and end the festivals early, or are there consequences for ignoring NPCs?** Like do I end up losing relationship points if I ignore anyone during a festival?

Comment: You do lose -2 points if you don't to talk to given NPC at all in a day. That's instead of the 20 points you'd get it if you did. So assuming talking to a NPC during the festival counts as talking to them normally then you'd be missing out on your best opportunity that day to score those points with every villager and avoid all the penalties. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258243/do-relationships-degrade-over-time

Answer (score 2):

It's really weird. short answer no, talking to villagers at festivals does not affect their affection (at least not during the egg festival I just checked. I'm guessing all the other festivals are similar)

Long answer, I made a backup of my save. I loaded up the game; I was on the day of the egg festival. I talked to Linus before the festivals. I went to the festival; I talked to as many people as I was able to. I won the festival. I left and I happened to find Pam and Sebastian to talk to. I saved and quit the game.

I looked at my save file and the changes were: Lewis, Sam, Wizard and Dwarf went up 8(?) points, Linues went up 30(?), Sebastian went up 20 and Pam went up 20. Everyone else went down 2 points.

This is of course as of March 17, 2016.